# Justified Alignment of Text in Inkscape Not Working

Tags: text-alignment, inkscape

As you can see in Inkscape, it's impossible to align text in "Justified". The icon is permanently disabled. Left and right are working fine, but Justified is not. Could anyone please suggest some workaround? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had exactly the same problem.  The trick is to create a new empty text box first using the text tool.  At this point you should be able to select the "Justified" icon from the text alignment drop down, as well as selecting which font, font size etc you want.  ONLY THEN paste or type in your text.

I guess you were doing what I was doing before I realised this.  I was just clicking where I wanted my text to start with the text tool.  I then typed some text and then used the cursor to alter the enclosing text box.  I then went to the text alignment drop down and found that the justified button was greyed out.

Comment: One other thing which might help.  If you are pasting from MS-Word, the embedded formatting within your selection may cause inkspace to paste your text into an entirely new text box that of course you haven't justified.  If you have this problem, paste the text into a format free editor, such as notepad, then re-copy the text and then paste it into your justified inkspace text box.

Comment: Tried that, justified is selected but pasted text is still not justified. V. 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

For justified text in inkscape the following steps:

1. select text tool
2. select justifying
3. draw the text box
4. type the text